# Seagate Expansion power cable

Tags: hard-drive, cable

I have a seagate expansion hard drive, the [previous version](http://www.pricerunner.se/pl/36-1223156/Haarddiskar/Seagate-Desktop-1TB-USB2.0-7200rpm-(ST310005EXD101-RK)-priser). I lost my power cable. I'm from Sweden, and I can't find it (unless I ship it for $50).

Maybe I can find the correct name of the power cable, and then see if it's a standard I can buy in Sweden. But I don't know how to identify it, thus my question.

The symbol on my seagate looks like this

```
- - - 
_____
```

and here is a [photo](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wa5h1vz8u33m38y/2013-07-29%2011.30.33.jpg) of it.

Comment: The photo link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

Get one of these.  They're called "universal A/C adapters" and among the plugs provided you'll find one that fits the drive.

[image: A picture of a universal A/C adapter]